# rake spec failed, it cannot load or find constant or global variable

Tags: ruby, rspec, rake, yaml, rakefile

I create standalone rspec test script to testing existing api framework. It works pretty well, but I found problem where in the Rakefile I need to assign some value from YAML file (uri link, email) either `CONSTANT` or `$global_var` the code in the Rakefile looks like this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'yaml'
require 'rspec/core/rake_task'

task :default => :spec

desc 'Running rspec test'
  task :spec, :option  do |t, opt|
    choice = opt[:choice]
    if choice == "production"
      puts 'Test running on production'
      VAR = YAML::load(File.read(File.expand_path("../config/prod_variable.yml", __FILE__)))
     elsif choice == "development"
      puts 'Test running on development'
      VAR = YAML::load(File.read(File.expand_path("../config/dev_variable.yml", __FILE__)))
     end

      puts VAR['URI'] #=> print out the value correctly

      RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new do |task|
        test = Rake.application.original_dir
        task.fail_on_error = false
        task.rspec_opts = '--format documentation --color'
      end
  end
```

When I run the rake command on the terminal, the rspec failed find the `VAR` constant value. Here is the error message from rspec

```
Failures:

  1) ApiTest Testing API platform for GET request 
     Failure/Error: @var = ApiTest.new(VAR['URI'] ,
     NameError:
       uninitialized constant VAR
     # ./rspec_test/api_test/api_test_get_spec.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) ApiTest Testing API platform for POST request   
     Failure/Error: @zat = ApiTest.new(VAR['URI'] ,
     NameError:
       uninitialized constant VAR
     # ./rspec_test/api_test/api_test_post_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Is there any idea how to get this works? I need to get value from VAR constant or global variable, but seems ruby failed to assign the value.

Answer (score 0):

If `opt[:choice]` is neither `"production"` nor `"development"`, `VAR` is undefined in your code.

Comment: Please check the value of `opt[:choice]` or `choice`.

Comment: opt[:choice] or choice did not show the value, it just show the empty hash.
I just rea;ize there are mo value on both this.

Comment: Yes. And in that case `VAR` is not defined.

Comment: YEs, seems like the add argument on the rake task is not possible but on current rake version this is probably bugs. I change the logic of the if statement and make it works. Thanks @iltempo